# Is there a way to outline a GameObject through a C# script in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My question is in the title. Basically what I want to do is to create an outline around an object when you hover over it with your mouse. The only thing I know is that I need to write the code inside an `OnMouseOver` event function.

Every answer appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You can do this with the right shader. I think brackeys did one.

Comment: This shader on the asset store worked for me, its free https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/particles-effects/quick-outline-115488

Comment: Your first assumption is already wrong: it should probably rather be `OnMouseEnter` and `OnMouseExit`. Then please note that questions mainly asking for a tutorial or external library/tool are off-topic here. Do your own research and come back with a specific questions when you have trouble implementing a specific solution.

Answer (score -2):

Basically you have to create two gameobject. The second gameobject will be your outline:

```
public GameObject secondGameObject;

private void OnMouseOver()
{
    secondGameObject.SetActive(true);
}

private void OnMouseExit()
{
    secondGameObject.SetActive(false);

}
```

Comment: Please don't do that, even if it works, is better to use a shader